# How to delete Watson Assistant server logs API V2

Tags: watson-assistant

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-information-security#information-security-gdpr-wa

Above article describes how to delete watson assistant server logs using V1, Does V2 has this feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is no V2 API for it yet. You will need to use the V1.

Comment: I tried but still I dont see the customer id updated in X-Watson-Metadata in the response headers. Using python SDK.

Comment: V2 api does work same way as V1. add customer id in headers and use 'https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/user_data' in delete requests

Answer (score 0):

Use requests.delete('https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/user_data', params=params, auth=('apikey', 'apikey')). Tried and works